# error with angular: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: angular

i forked **totally working** simple angular cli project 
however when i run it i get this error

angular cli styles normal:

```
     "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "./styles.css"
  ],
```

have no idea what the problem could be, and what kind of information i should deliver here

**thanks!**

> Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
>       at assertArrayOfStrings (compiler.es5.js:3920)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15170)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15092)
>       at compiler.es5.js:26802
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at compiler.es5.js:26801
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26798)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26768)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26697)

Comment: have you tried using `styleUrls` instead of `styles`?

Comment: yes, no change (also quite surprising) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your components, make sure that you have `styleUrls` or `styles`  inside an array i.e. `[ ]`

E.g.

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
```

You dont have to change the `.angular-cli` styles []

Comment: thanks! in the components it is only "styleUrls" that reference component css

Comment: Yes, put that inside [ ]

Comment: e.g. `styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']`

Comment: thay all are.
i dont think it is some syntex error, again, i forked it form working project
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I encountered this error when I tried to upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 9, so I downgraded raw-loader in my package.json to 1.0.0 to resolve the issue:

```
"raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
```

Where I also had my styles indicated like this:

```
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
```